# Cancelling a CSS rule

Tags: css

Let's say we have the following CSS default rule X, declared in a WordPress child theme:

```
.btn { background: url("btn.jpg"); }
```

And this rule Y, declared in commercial parent WordPress theme:

```
.btn:hover { background: gray; }
```

Can I somehow tell the browser "ignore Y", so that nothing will happen when hovering the .btn element?

Comment: You don't cancel CSS rules, you override them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your only option is overriding the value of `.btn:hover` with the same value as `.btn`:

```css
.btn:hover { background: url("btn.jpg"); }
```

```css
.btn { background: red; }
.btn:hover { background: blue; }
/* ... */
.btn:hover { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="btn">Foo</div>
```